# Use Automatic1111 on an Intel Mac?

Tags: stable-diffusion, automatic1111-sd-web-ui

Is it possible to run the Automatic111 web UI on a Intel MacPro 2013 desktop computer. I did the install by (meant for M1 Mac) and the Terminal app won’t open the website.sh.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [architectures / operating systems supported by AUTOMATIC1111 / stable-diffusion-webui](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/tree/7d94e5f33b700e86fae9bd9cb842f51fe422d175#installation-and-running):

- Windows
- Linux
- Apple Silicon

Your MacPro uses a x86(64) architecture that doesn't exist in this list, so there is no official support.

---

However the GitHub user Chocovanilazuki wrote a [guide to install this tool on the same architecture](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/2409#issuecomment-1290150405) than you, it's worth a try.